# Angular Service Worker not being registered

Tags: angular, angular-cli, service-worker

I am trying to register service worker in my angular application but its not working. ng add @angular/pwa did not work so I first installed angular service worker using npm like this

```
npm install @angular/service-worker@9.1.1
```

and then added **ngsw-config.json** file in src directory which looks like this:

```
{
 "index": "/index.html",
 "assetGroups": [{
 "name": "app",
 "installMode": "prefetch",
 "resources": {
  "files": [
    "/favicon.ico",
    "/index.html",
    "/*.css",
    "/*.js"
    ]
   }
 }]
}
```

to **angular.json** file I added:

```
"serviceWorker": true,
"ngswConfigPath": "ngsw-config.json"
```

and finally registered it in **app.module.ts** like this

```
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })
```

once i did all of that i ran ng build --prod. Finally I ran the app using http-server. once I checked the devtools there was service worker tab but it didn't say that it was active. I don't know what I am doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

I have node 16.20.2 version and these are some other package versions:

```
@angular-devkit/architect                  0.901.13
@angular-devkit/build-angular              0.901.9
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer            0.901.9
@angular-devkit/build-webpack              0.901.9
@angular-devkit/core                       9.1.13
@angular-devkit/schematics                 9.1.13
@angular/cli                               9.1.13
@ngtools/webpack                           9.1.9
@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader   v8.2.6
@schematics/angular                        9.1.13
@schematics/update                         0.901.13
rxjs                                       6.5.5
typescript                                 3.7.5
webpack                                    4.42.0
```